# New fungus or mold on my basil plant soil

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, basil, mold

My husband and I are new to gardening. We bought a basil plant a month or so again, and we've been cutting it and starting new plants. Today woke up to this weird mold or fungus. I can't seem to find pictures of it anywhere online, and I also can't seem to upload pics of my own. But it's pale orange/white. It kind of looks like Ritz cracker crumbs. It's in 3 separate localized areas on the soil at the base of my basil stems. We don't over water, just give it a good soaking every few days when the soil feels dry, but yesterday we had quite a rainstorm. My phone said it'd be light rain so I left the plants outside -- I had calendula growing in pots without drain holes, which flooded and I had to do "emergency gardening" and replant them. Is this just from too much water from one day? It's in well draining soil, and in a pot with a large hole with rocks at the bottom. 
Help! Do I leave it and it'll go away once the soil becomes really dry? Or do I need to scrape it off and/or an inch or two of soil out? I sure wish I could post pics!

Comment: Welcome to the site! The simplest way to add pictures is to press on the gray word that says "edit" or just press on this [edit]. Your question will open up. Along the top before your text are some icons. One looks kind of like a mountain with a dot in the right hand corner. Press on that and a window will open with an option to post a picture from your computer or from a website. A picture of your own is always best! If that's not helpful, please leave us a note and we'll get you to a more detailed process.

Comment: Yep, photo would be good - sounds like some sort of slime mould at the moment.

Comment: Are you using regular garden soil from your yard in these pots? BAD! Send pictures!! Only bagged soil!! Quite adventurous to grow basil from starts when it is far easier to do by seed.  I'd never grow vegetatively (leaf cuts).  Seed is the prefered way unless you are a crazy obsessive gardener that needs a challenge!  When you get more experience with gardening that would be just fine.  NO ROCKS ON THE BOTTOM of the pot.  That creates a 'perched water table' which impairs drainage.  Only soil in a pot with a hole and get the bottom off the surface to creat air space for better drainage.

Comment: Hi Jena! Are you still waiting for some help with your issues? I'm going to vote to close this question, just because without details we can't really be sure what you're asking. That's explained in the [help] on [this page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). You still have time to edit your post. If we don't hear from you, we hope all is well and your problem is solved!